# ¿Como validar los espacios en JavaScript en las clases?

Tags: javascript, poo, validación

Estaba realizando un ejercicio de clases en JS y con el calculo de IVA del mismo pero si bien me funciona en otras validaciones que tambien utilizan otras exp Reg la de espacios no me funciona probe con varias exp Reg, la idea es que el nombre que valide que cada palabra tenga espacio si o si. Lo raro es que si valida bien si se coloca en una función externa y no como método calcule que sera algun fallo de lógica de mi parte a la hora de escribir la clase por lo que me gustaria saber cual es la mejor exp Reg para los espacios entre palabras y porque no valida dentro de la clase.

Aca mí código:

La funcion que valida los espacios:

```
validarEspacios(propiedad,valor){
        if(!(/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/g.test(valor))) return console.error(`${propiedad} "${valor}" debe estar seperados con espacio y tener dos palabras claves al menos.`);

        return console.log(true);
    }
```

El método que valida el nombre:

```
validarNombre(nombre){
        if(this.validarString("Nombre",nombre)){
            if(this.validarCaracteres("Nombre", nombre,50)){
                this.validarEspacios("Nombre",nombre);
                
            }
        }
    }
```

````
class cuerpoIvaEspaña{
    constructor({id,ubicacion,nombre,monto}){
        this.id = id;
        this.ubicacion = ubicacion;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.monto = monto;
    }

    validarNumero(propiedad,valor){
        if(!valor) return console.warn(`${propiedad} NO esta definido`);

        if(typeof valor !== "number") return console.error(`El  "${propiedad} NO es un número.`);

        if(Math.sing(valor)===-1) return console.error(`El ${propiedad} tiene que ser positivo`);

        return true;
    }

    validarString(propiedad,valor){
        
        if(!valor)return console.warn(`${propiedad} "${valor}" NO esta definido`);

        
        if(typeof valor !== "string")return console.error(`${propiedad} NO es un string`);

        if(valor.length===0) return console.error(`${propiedad} "${valor}" NO tiene ningun caracter.`);

        return true;
    }

    validarEspacios(propiedad,valor){
        if(!(/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/g.test(valor))) return console.error(`${propiedad} "${valor}" debe estar seperados con espacio y tener dos palabras claves al menos.`);

        return console.log(true);
    }

    validarCaracteres(propiedad,valor,longitud){
        if(valor.length>longitud) return console.error(`${propiedad} "${valor}" excede el número de caracteres permitidos ${longitud}`);
    }

    validarID(id){
        if(this.validarString("ID",id)){
            if(!(/^([1-7]){7}([a-z]{2})$/.test(id))) return console.error("ID no valido");
        }
    }

    validarNombre(nombre){
        if(this.validarString("Nombre",nombre)){
            if(this.validarCaracteres("Nombre", nombre,50)){
                this.validarEspacios("Nombre",nombre);
                
            }
        }
    }

    validarValor(monto){
        if(this.validarNumero("Monto",monto)){
            if(/^([0-9])\b(,[0-9]){1}([0-9]{1})/.test(valor.toString())) return console.error(`El Monto NO puede tener más de dos valores despues de la coma`);
        }
    }
}



class IVA21 extends cuerpoIvaEspaña{
    constructor({id,nombre,ubicacion,monto,tipoDeServicioOVenta}){

        super(id,nombre,ubicacion,monto);
        
        this.tipoDeServicioOVenta = tipoDeServicioOVenta;

        this.validarID(id);
        this.validarNombre(nombre);
        //this.validarValor()

    }
    static get ventasNombres(){
        return ["Vestimenta","Coches","Motocicletas","Higiene","Cosméticos","Electrodomésticos",];
    }

    static get servicioNombres(){
        return ["Luz","Gas","Combustible","Internet"]
    }

    static ventasAceptadas(){
        return console.info(`Los nombres aceptados y tipos de ventas son: ${IVA21.ventasNombres.join(", ")}.`);
    }

    static serviciosAceptados(){
        return console.info(`Los nombres aceptados y tipos de servicios son: ${IVA21.servicioNombres.join(", ")}.`);
    }
}

//IVA21.ventasAceptadas();
//IVA21.serviciosAceptados();

const cuerpo = new IVA21({
    id:"1234567ab",
    nombre:"Mercadona"
}); ```
````

Comment: cual es el propósito de tener un `if` sin cuerpo? `if(this.validarEspacios("Nombre", nombre));` porque no llamas a la funcion y listo? Y probablemente no te valida los espacios porque el `validaCaracteres` no devuelve nada, debes devolver `true` si no hay errores para que entre en el condicional para que ejecute `validarEspacios`

Comment: SI tenes razon ahí cambie el código deberia retonar un true pero en el ejemplo que uso en la ultima linea de código cuando defino "cuerpo" no retorna el error() que coloque es más tampoco retorna verdadero no se porque a un

Comment: Ahí pude encontrar mi error era en otra funcion que le faltaba retonar true para que ejecute la otra funcion y arregle la expresion regular colocando solo **/\s/g** y ahí cumple con la evalaución de los espacios me gustaria saber como hacer mejor la expresion regular o que otra expresion regular serio mejor muchas gracias